# How do JMS selectors scale with queue depth?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

What is the algorithmic time complexity of applying JMS selectors when consuming messages from a queue, with respect to queue depth *n*? In particular, is it linear (O(n)) per read? Is it implementation-dependent (on the JMS provider), and does it depend on what fields are being requested?

(if implementation dependent, I'm particularly interested in Websphere MQ and Solace's behaviour, but I welcome answers that deal with any particular JMS provider, especially if you have links to documentation describing the complexity!).

**Motivation**: each message has two properties: an `invocationID` and a `batchName`. A batch consists of several invocations. Clients wish to consume messages in one of two ways; either by `invocationID` or by `batchName`. At the point that messages are produced, I don't know by which method they will be consumed.

This can be implemented through selectors:

```
invocationID=42
```

Or

```
batchName="reconciliation"
```

...and I can speed one of these up by using the correlation ID instead of a custom property, but am concerned that the other will remain slow.

Comment: Great question! I suspect this is very hard to get a good answer to, but is obviously of fundamental importance for making certain architectural decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg20170_.htm), the messages are searched sequentially.  WMQ does however index the `MessageID` and `CorrelID` fields.  The Infocenter describes the behavior as follows:

> Selecting messages from a queue requires WebSphere MQ to sequentially
>   inspect each message on the queue. Messages are inspected until a
>   message is found that matches the selection criteria or there are no
>   more messages to examine. Therefore, messaging performance suffers if
>   message selection is used on deep queues.
>
> To optimize message selection on deep queues when selection is based
>   on JMSCorrelationID or JMSMessageID, use a selection string of the
>   form JMSCorrelationID = ... or JMSMessageID = ... and reference only
>   one property.
>
> This method offers a significant improvement in performance for
>   selection on JMSCorrelationID and offers a marginal performance
>   improvement for JMSMessageID.

I would love to understand more about the requirement to multiplex queues.  A complex selector is going to impact performance on anyone's implementation and the alternative of using multiple open handles with simpler selectors is no different to the app code than using multiple queues.  For WMQ of course, dynamic queues or many permanently defined queues is no problem at all.  Very often when I see this requirement, it comes from shops that have used certain other transports where performance takes a severe dive with many queues defined and there is an assumption that this is true on WMQ as well.  In other cases the requirement has been met with Pub/Sub and durable subscriptions.  I'm not suggesting there are no valid cases for this requirement, just wondering what is driving it.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the link! The selectors themselves won't be complex (probably just equality on 1 property) - it just won't necessarily be on correlationid! (which is already used).

Comment: My selectors aren't complex; I've added a bit of detail on my motivation, and removed the mention of multiplexing since it was a bit inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It sounds almost like a Pub/Sub problem.  One copy of the messages could be placed on a queue using an administrative subscription and clients can retrieve the messages by CorrelID.  Clients interested in the other property could simply subscribe to it as a topic.  These could be dynamic or durable subscriptions but because the selection would be evaluated at publication, each client would get only the messages it was interested in and could simply read its subscription queue FIFO. Of course, if the selections change at run time this doesn't work.

Comment: How does one "subscribe to it [*the queue?*] as a topic" such that "selection would be evaluated at publication"? I don't understand what functionality you're describing.

Comment: Whenever a subscription is made, the eligible messages are delivered to the subscriber's queue which can be pre-defined or dynamic.  The subscription itself defines the selection criteria which can include topics and message properties.  The QMgr evaluates the selection criteria at publication time and delivers appropriate messages to the right queues. Since the subscription can be defined administratively, the app consuming the messages does not need to subscribe directly but can continue to consume from a queue, although now it only ever receives messages it is interested in.

Comment: I think what you're describing means that each results ends up on 1 queue for matching by correlationID and (sometimes) on a separate, possibly dynamic, selection-criteria-specific queue for clients wanting to match by the other criteria (`batchID`). Won't this mean such messages will be duplicated on 2 queues, meaning they'll linger until expiry on the queue that isn't read?

Comment: They already linger until expiry in the scenario described in the question. Performing the selection at publication time and by the QMgr instead of the app allows some or all of them to be pre-selected so they don't.

Comment: I must have described something badly if you think that - in the original scenario, each message is published only once (with multiple properties set) and once consumed by one client is no longer on any queue.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the implementation. A lot of JMS providers store messages in a SQL database so they can use SQL for selector implementation. In this case you would have to look how your particular case is mapped into SQL.

As for WebSphereMQ - the selector implementation is O(log n) for `JMSMessageID = sth` and `JMSCorrelationID = sth`, for the others I have no specific knowledge. From experience it looks like O(n) though.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know the WMQ complexity for those fields - do you have links to any documentation, or is this based on profiling/guesswork?

Comment: @bacar A few (more about like ten) years ago I was involved in a project which heavily used WMQ and we did some performance tests. The analysis showed us that the complexity is as I've written. I haven't found it in any documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

With WebSphere MQ version 7 the implementation of selectors was altered. With a v7 JMS client and v7 QueueManager, the selection processing is done QueueManager side.  With a v6 JMS Client (or in fact a v7 client working in it's migration) mode, all messages are flowed across to the client to processing.  If the hit rate of a matching message was low there was a lot of wasted effort. So

With v7 the processing is done QueueManager side so only messages that match are sent to the client.

Keep in mind that the QueueManager doesn't maintain complex indexes of message properties as a database would. So the simpler selectors are the better.

Comment: Thanks. All useful info, but it could still be linear whether I use v6 or v7 - that is, while v7 can do the work on the server rather than the client, possibly more efficiently, the work done may still involve scanning every message on the queue (O(n)) to find one that matches the selector.